# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'netCDF4'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, netcdf4

I am trying to create a lambda function that uses netCDF4. Unfortunately it seems netCDF4 is not supported in AWS. Is there a way to use netCDF4 in AWS?

Update: I created the zip file, however another module is missing (netCDF4._netCDF4) within the module I originally created the zip file for. Has anyone actually used specifically netCDF4 in a lambda function? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use netCDF4 in AWS?

Yes. There are three options for you:

- [Bundle your netCDF4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package-create.html#python-package-create-with-dependency) with your lambda zip package.
- Create [lambda layer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-lambda-layers-to-simplify-your-development-process/) with netCDF4
- Use [container lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) which comprises of your entire codebase including all dependencies.

Comment: After creating  the zip for netCDF4, another module appears to be missing. Here is the error: {
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'netCDF4._netCDF4'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}

Comment: @Arec Just create container lambda. This is the easiest way to handle lambda dependencies. Everything else is more complex to handle.

Comment: Honestly it seems more complex than the first option. I am still new to AWS, but I appreciate your help. I feel like I did everything correctly with the first option (which I just watched a YouTube video since I find it easier to follow along), but some how another module is missing.

Comment: @Arec Doesn't netCDF4 depend on C libraries as well? AWS lambda will not have them either.

Comment: When I pip install netCDF4, in the netCDF directory, _netCDF4.cp39-win_amd64.pyd is the only thing that is close to the _netCDF4 that is missing. Is this file related to the issue?

Comment: lambda environment is not windows. Seems you are install `win_` based dependencies.

Comment: Any recommendations?

Comment: If I can't find the linux version of netCDF4, is my only option is to run my code in an ec2 instance?

Comment: @Arec You can install it in lambda container and lambda layer, or create your dependencies package on Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: I'm using layers but it's not working. After adding the layer to the function, when I test the function it still doesn't recognize the package. Does my python version must match the version of the lambda function and layer? I have python3.9

Comment: I would suggest making a new question with exact steps you take to create the layer and relevant error messages.

Comment: I got it to work! I forgot I had a laptop with Linux. I just pip installed netCDF4 into a directory along with the python file and  zipped it. I was able to upload the dependency via zip file but i was unable to use a layer. I completed the layer just like i did with uploading the zip file except not zipping the python file with it. Nevertheless, thank you for helping me.

Comment: @Arec Glad it worked out. If my answer and comments were helpful, it's acceptance would be appreciated.